# Get a process's environment variables

Tags: python, virtual-machine

I am looking for a simple way to collect data from a process running on guest.
I've tried get the data via process's environment variables, but pysphere works only with system's the variables, which cannot be modified by the process easily.

`get_environment_variables`

*Reads the environment variables from the guest OS (system user). Returns
        a dictionary where keys are the var names and the dict value is the var
        value.*

Is there way to get exactly process's environment variables in pysphere?
Or how to periodically get data(short strings) from a process which has not finished yet on guest?